# How to find parameters supported in Tesseract OCR config file

Tags: tesseract

I want to know what parameters the config file used by Tesseract OCR accepts, how to write a config file, etc.

I can't find any documentation about this on [their site](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/). How can I determine what parameters are supported, and what they mean?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ControlParams

Comment: Example config files: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/tree/master/tessdata/configs

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Tesseract v3.04 now offers the command line option `--print-parameters`, so you can call `tesseract --print-parameters` to get a list of the 678 (!) configurable parameters, their default values, and a short description:

```
Tesseract parameters:
editor_image_xpos   590 Editor image X Pos
editor_image_ypos   10  Editor image Y Pos
editor_image_menuheight 50  Add to image height for menu bar
editor_image_word_bb_color  7   Word bounding box colour
editor_image_blob_bb_color  4   Blob bounding box colour
editor_image_text_color 2   Correct text colour
...and many, many more
```

Comment: I can't work out how to feed a file generated from this, after modification, back into Tesseract - any ideas :\

Comment: @jtlz2 ooh, good _question_! Esp. considering tesseract is currently a whole major version (4.1.0) newer than when I posted my answer, you should re-post that as a new question.

Comment: like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57794165/tesseract-differing-output-how-do-i-find-out-which-parameters-are-being-used

Comment: Is there any documentation on each of them in the official docs?

Answer (score 19):

I found these instructions in the link below. They are about writing the config file and where to place it:

> config file is simple text file without BOM and with Unix end-of-line mark (on Windows you can use some advanced text editor e.g. Notepad++ to achieve this).
>
> If you use tesseract executable this is only way how to change tesseract parameters.
>
> config file should be located in your tessdata/configs directory. Have a look there for some examples.

There is a **list of all the variables** plus descriptions of each one in http://www.sk-spell.sk.cx/tesseract-ocr-parameters-in-302-version. Note it's for Tesseract 3.02, things may be different in other versions.

**Edit:** Also adding a [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/av7huwQP) in case the above link becomes dead.

Answer (score 10):

It's just a plain text file containing space-delimited key/value pairs for Tesseract config variables, each on separate line; for instance:

```
interactive_display_mode T
tessedit_display_outwords T
```

There are several standard config files -- such as digits, hocr -- under Tesseract [tessdata/configs](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/browse/#svn/trunk/tessdata/configs) folder.

Comment: Where can I find a list of all the config variables, and of the values they can take?

Comment: Please refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087252/where-i-can-find-the-list-of-available-property-name-for-tesseract-setvariable

Comment: and... how the file config is saved? i mean,... what filename should i gave to it? and... how do the command "tesseract" use that config file specifically? :( I'm a bit confused. @nguyenq