# Where I can find the list of available property name for tesseract->setvariable function's first parameter?

Tags: ios, xcode, tesseract

From the lots of goggling I am able to find only few of them as the below example for tesseract's setVariable(1st param, 2nd param)

```
tesseract->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
tesseract->SetVariable("language_model_penalty_non_freq_dict_word", "0");
tesseract->SetVariable("language_model_penalty_non_dict_word", "0");
tesseract->SetVariable("tessedit_char_blacklist", "xyz");
tesseract->SetVariable("classify_bln_numeric_mode", "1");
```

I would like to know how much more of them are there?

Is there any list available? If any please give me the link to it.

Comment: http://www.sk-spell.sk.cx/tesseract-ocr-parameters-in-302-version

Comment: Thanks for this question. Just a quick hint: You have a space after language_model_penalty_non_dict_word. So line 3 will be ignored if you run it like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code should do the trick for iOS... might need a bit of tweaking.

```
bool verboseOut = true;

if (verboseOut) {        //Write to console current Settings
   char buffer [256];
   FILE * pFile = tmpfile();
   tesseract->PrintVariables(pFile);
   rewind(pFile);
   while (!feof(pFile)) {
      if (fgets (buffer,256,pFile))
            fputs (buffer,stdout);
   } fclose(pFile);
}
```

Comment: This code works like charm Thanks for reply :). This is exactly what I am looking for. :)

Comment: this can't really be applied in iOS (cant write to a file handle). Any ideas how to do this in iOS? Maybe someone could just include a list of all the variable here.

Comment: @roocell to use this code have to change the file extension from .m to .mm

Answer (score 19):

For all you frustrated iOS coders out there.
Found the list in the header tesseractclass.h
here's the list

```
 BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_resegment_from_boxes, false,
             "Take segmentation and labeling from box file");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_resegment_from_line_boxes, false,
              "Conversion of word/line box file to char box file");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_train_from_boxes, false,
             "Generate training data from boxed chars");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_make_boxes_from_boxes, false,
             "Generate more boxes from boxed chars");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_dump_pageseg_images, false,
             "Dump intermediate images made during page segmentation");
  INT_VAR_H(tessedit_pageseg_mode, PSM_SINGLE_BLOCK,
            "Page seg mode: 0=osd only, 1=auto+osd, 2=auto, 3=col, 4=block,"
            " 5=line, 6=word, 7=char"
            " (Values from PageSegMode enum in publictypes.h)");
  INT_VAR_H(tessedit_ocr_engine_mode, tesseract::OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY,
            "Which OCR engine(s) to run (Tesseract, Cube, both). Defaults"
            " to loading and running only Tesseract (no Cube, no combiner)."
            " (Values from OcrEngineMode enum in tesseractclass.h)");
  STRING_VAR_H(tessedit_char_blacklist, "",
               "Blacklist of chars not to recognize");
  STRING_VAR_H(tessedit_char_whitelist, "",
               "Whitelist of chars to recognize");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_ambigs_training, false,
             "Perform training for ambiguities");
  INT_VAR_H(pageseg_devanagari_split_strategy,
            tesseract::ShiroRekhaSplitter::NO_SPLIT,
            "Whether to use the top-line splitting process for Devanagari "
            "documents while performing page-segmentation.");
  INT_VAR_H(ocr_devanagari_split_strategy,
            tesseract::ShiroRekhaSplitter::NO_SPLIT,
            "Whether to use the top-line splitting process for Devanagari "
            "documents while performing ocr.");
  STRING_VAR_H(tessedit_write_params_to_file, "",
               "Write all parameters to the given file.");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_adapt_to_char_fragments, true,
             "Adapt to words that contain "
             " a character composed form fragments");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_adaption_debug, false,
             "Generate and print debug information for adaption");
  INT_VAR_H(bidi_debug, 0, "Debug level for BiDi");
  INT_VAR_H(applybox_debug, 1, "Debug level");
  INT_VAR_H(applybox_page, 0, "Page number to apply boxes from");
  STRING_VAR_H(applybox_exposure_pattern, ".exp",
               "Exposure value follows this pattern in the image"
               " filename. The name of the image files are expected"
               " to be in the form [lang].[fontname].exp[num].tif");
  BOOL_VAR_H(applybox_learn_chars_and_char_frags_mode, false,
             "Learn both character fragments (as is done in the"
             " special low exposure mode) as well as unfragmented"
             " characters.");
  BOOL_VAR_H(applybox_learn_ngrams_mode, false,
             "Each bounding box is assumed to contain ngrams. Only"
             " learn the ngrams whose outlines overlap horizontally.");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_display_outwords, false, "Draw output words");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_training_tess, false, "Call Tess to learn blobs");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_dump_choices, false, "Dump char choices");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_fix_fuzzy_spaces, true,
             "Try to improve fuzzy spaces");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_unrej_any_wd, false,
             "Dont bother with word plausibility");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_fix_hyphens, true, "Crunch double hyphens?");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_redo_xheight, true, "Check/Correct x-height");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_enable_doc_dict, true,
             "Add words to the document dictionary");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_debug_fonts, false, "Output font info per char");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_debug_block_rejection, false, "Block and Row stats");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_enable_bigram_correction, false,
             "Enable correction based on the word bigram dictionary.");
  INT_VAR_H(tessedit_bigram_debug, 0, "Amount of debug output for bigram "
            "correction.");
  INT_VAR_H(debug_x_ht_level, 0, "Reestimate debug");
  BOOL_VAR_H(debug_acceptable_wds, false, "Dump word pass/fail chk");
  STRING_VAR_H(chs_leading_punct, "('`\"", "Leading punctuation");
  STRING_VAR_H(chs_trailing_punct1, ").,;:?!", "1st Trailing punctuation");
  STRING_VAR_H(chs_trailing_punct2, ")'`\"", "2nd Trailing punctuation");
  double_VAR_H(quality_rej_pc, 0.08, "good_quality_doc lte rejection limit");
  double_VAR_H(quality_blob_pc, 0.0, "good_quality_doc gte good blobs limit");
  double_VAR_H(quality_outline_pc, 1.0,
               "good_quality_doc lte outline error limit");
  double_VAR_H(quality_char_pc, 0.95, "good_quality_doc gte good char limit");
  INT_VAR_H(quality_min_initial_alphas_reqd, 2, "alphas in a good word");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_tess_adapt_to_rejmap, false,
             "Use reject map to control Tesseract adaption");
  INT_VAR_H(tessedit_tess_adaption_mode, 0x27,
            "Adaptation decision algorithm for tess");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_minimal_rej_pass1, false,
             "Do minimal rejection on pass 1 output");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_test_adaption, false, "Test adaption criteria");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_matcher_log, false, "Log matcher activity");
  INT_VAR_H(tessedit_test_adaption_mode, 3,
            "Adaptation decision algorithm for tess");
  BOOL_VAR_H(save_blob_choices, false,
             "Save the results of the recognition step"
             " (blob_choices) within the corresponding WERD_CHOICE");
  BOOL_VAR_H(test_pt, false, "Test for point");
  double_VAR_H(test_pt_x, 99999.99, "xcoord");
  double_VAR_H(test_pt_y, 99999.99, "ycoord");
  INT_VAR_H(paragraph_debug_level, 0, "Print paragraph debug info.");
  INT_VAR_H(cube_debug_level, 1, "Print cube debug info.");
  STRING_VAR_H(outlines_odd, "%| ", "Non standard number of outlines");
  STRING_VAR_H(outlines_2, "ij!?%\":;", "Non standard number of outlines");
  BOOL_VAR_H(docqual_excuse_outline_errs, false,
             "Allow outline errs in unrejection?");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_good_quality_unrej, true,
             "Reduce rejection on good docs");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_use_reject_spaces, true, "Reject spaces?");
  double_VAR_H(tessedit_reject_doc_percent, 65.00,
               "%rej allowed before rej whole doc");
  double_VAR_H(tessedit_reject_block_percent, 45.00,
               "%rej allowed before rej whole block");
  double_VAR_H(tessedit_reject_row_percent, 40.00,
               "%rej allowed before rej whole row");
  double_VAR_H(tessedit_whole_wd_rej_row_percent, 70.00,
               "Number of row rejects in whole word rejects"
               "which prevents whole row rejection");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_preserve_blk_rej_perfect_wds, true,
             "Only rej partially rejected words in block rejection");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_preserve_row_rej_perfect_wds, true,
             "Only rej partially rejected words in row rejection");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_dont_blkrej_good_wds, false,
             "Use word segmentation quality metric");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_dont_rowrej_good_wds, false,
             "Use word segmentation quality metric");
  INT_VAR_H(tessedit_preserve_min_wd_len, 2,
            "Only preserve wds longer than this");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_row_rej_good_docs, true,
             "Apply row rejection to good docs");
  double_VAR_H(tessedit_good_doc_still_rowrej_wd, 1.1,
               "rej good doc wd if more than this fraction rejected");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_reject_bad_qual_wds, true,
             "Reject all bad quality wds");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_debug_doc_rejection, false, "Page stats");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_debug_quality_metrics, false,
             "Output data to debug file");
  BOOL_VAR_H(bland_unrej, false, "unrej potential with no chekcs");
  double_VAR_H(quality_rowrej_pc, 1.1,
               "good_quality_doc gte good char limit");
  BOOL_VAR_H(unlv_tilde_crunching, true,
             "Mark v.bad words for tilde crunch");
  BOOL_VAR_H(crunch_early_merge_tess_fails, true, "Before word crunch?");
  BOOL_VAR_H(crunch_early_convert_bad_unlv_chs, false, "Take out ~^ early?");
  double_VAR_H(crunch_terrible_rating, 80.0, "crunch rating lt this");
  BOOL_VAR_H(crunch_terrible_garbage, true, "As it says");
  double_VAR_H(crunch_poor_garbage_cert, -9.0,
               "crunch garbage cert lt this");
  double_VAR_H(crunch_poor_garbage_rate, 60, "crunch garbage rating lt this");
  double_VAR_H(crunch_pot_poor_rate, 40, "POTENTIAL crunch rating lt this");
  double_VAR_H(crunch_pot_poor_cert, -8.0, "POTENTIAL crunch cert lt this");
  BOOL_VAR_H(crunch_pot_garbage, true, "POTENTIAL crunch garbage");
  double_VAR_H(crunch_del_rating, 60, "POTENTIAL crunch rating lt this");
  double_VAR_H(crunch_del_cert, -10.0, "POTENTIAL crunch cert lt this");
  double_VAR_H(crunch_del_min_ht, 0.7, "Del if word ht lt xht x this");
  double_VAR_H(crunch_del_max_ht, 3.0, "Del if word ht gt xht x this");
  double_VAR_H(crunch_del_min_width, 3.0, "Del if word width lt xht x this");
  double_VAR_H(crunch_del_high_word, 1.5,
               "Del if word gt xht x this above bl");
  double_VAR_H(crunch_del_low_word, 0.5, "Del if word gt xht x this below bl");
  double_VAR_H(crunch_small_outlines_size, 0.6, "Small if lt xht x this");
  INT_VAR_H(crunch_rating_max, 10, "For adj length in rating per ch");
  INT_VAR_H(crunch_pot_indicators, 1, "How many potential indicators needed");
  BOOL_VAR_H(crunch_leave_ok_strings, true, "Dont touch sensible strings");
  BOOL_VAR_H(crunch_accept_ok, true, "Use acceptability in okstring");
  BOOL_VAR_H(crunch_leave_accept_strings, false,
             "Dont pot crunch sensible strings");
  BOOL_VAR_H(crunch_include_numerals, false, "Fiddle alpha figures");
  INT_VAR_H(crunch_leave_lc_strings, 4,
            "Dont crunch words with long lower case strings");
  INT_VAR_H(crunch_leave_uc_strings, 4,
            "Dont crunch words with long lower case strings");
  INT_VAR_H(crunch_long_repetitions, 3, "Crunch words with long repetitions");
  INT_VAR_H(crunch_debug, 0, "As it says");
  INT_VAR_H(fixsp_non_noise_limit, 1,
            "How many non-noise blbs either side?");
  double_VAR_H(fixsp_small_outlines_size, 0.28, "Small if lt xht x this");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_prefer_joined_punct, false, "Reward punctation joins");
  INT_VAR_H(fixsp_done_mode, 1, "What constitues done for spacing");
  INT_VAR_H(debug_fix_space_level, 0, "Contextual fixspace debug");
  STRING_VAR_H(numeric_punctuation, ".,",
               "Punct. chs expected WITHIN numbers");
  INT_VAR_H(x_ht_acceptance_tolerance, 8,
            "Max allowed deviation of blob top outside of font data");
  INT_VAR_H(x_ht_min_change, 8, "Min change in xht before actually trying it");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_write_block_separators, false,
             "Write block separators in output");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_write_rep_codes, false,
             "Write repetition char code");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_write_unlv, false, "Write .unlv output file");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_create_hocr, false, "Write .html hOCR output file");
  STRING_VAR_H(unrecognised_char, "|",
               "Output char for unidentified blobs");
  INT_VAR_H(suspect_level, 99, "Suspect marker level");
  INT_VAR_H(suspect_space_level, 100,
            "Min suspect level for rejecting spaces");
  INT_VAR_H(suspect_short_words, 2,
            "Dont Suspect dict wds longer than this");
  BOOL_VAR_H(suspect_constrain_1Il, false, "UNLV keep 1Il chars rejected");
  double_VAR_H(suspect_rating_per_ch, 999.9, "Dont touch bad rating limit");
  double_VAR_H(suspect_accept_rating, -999.9, "Accept good rating limit");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_minimal_rejection, false, "Only reject tess failures");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_zero_rejection, false, "Dont reject ANYTHING");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_word_for_word, false,
             "Make output have exactly one word per WERD");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_zero_kelvin_rejection, false,
             "Dont reject ANYTHING AT ALL");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_consistent_reps, true, "Force all rep chars the same");
  INT_VAR_H(tessedit_reject_mode, 0, "Rejection algorithm");
  INT_VAR_H(tessedit_ok_mode, 5, "Acceptance decision algorithm");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_rejection_debug, false, "Adaption debug");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_flip_0O, true, "Contextual 0O O0 flips");
  double_VAR_H(tessedit_lower_flip_hyphen, 1.5,
               "Aspect ratio dot/hyphen test");
  double_VAR_H(tessedit_upper_flip_hyphen, 1.8,
               "Aspect ratio dot/hyphen test");
  BOOL_VAR_H(rej_trust_doc_dawg, false, "Use DOC dawg in 11l conf. detector");
  BOOL_VAR_H(rej_1Il_use_dict_word, false, "Use dictword test");
  BOOL_VAR_H(rej_1Il_trust_permuter_type, true, "Dont double check");
  BOOL_VAR_H(rej_use_tess_accepted, true, "Individual rejection control");
  BOOL_VAR_H(rej_use_tess_blanks, true, "Individual rejection control");
  BOOL_VAR_H(rej_use_good_perm, true, "Individual rejection control");
  BOOL_VAR_H(rej_use_sensible_wd, false, "Extend permuter check");
  BOOL_VAR_H(rej_alphas_in_number_perm, false, "Extend permuter check");
  double_VAR_H(rej_whole_of_mostly_reject_word_fract, 0.85, "if >this fract");
  INT_VAR_H(tessedit_image_border, 2, "Rej blbs near image edge limit");
  STRING_VAR_H(ok_repeated_ch_non_alphanum_wds, "-?*\075",
               "Allow NN to unrej");
  STRING_VAR_H(conflict_set_I_l_1, "Il1[]", "Il1 conflict set");
  INT_VAR_H(min_sane_x_ht_pixels, 8, "Reject any x-ht lt or eq than this");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_create_boxfile, false, "Output text with boxes");
  INT_VAR_H(tessedit_page_number, -1,
            "-1 -> All pages, else specifc page to process");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_write_images, false, "Capture the image from the IPE");
  BOOL_VAR_H(interactive_display_mode, false, "Run interactively?");
  STRING_VAR_H(file_type, ".tif", "Filename extension");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_override_permuter, true, "According to dict_word");
  INT_VAR_H(tessdata_manager_debug_level, 0,
            "Debug level for TessdataManager functions.");
  STRING_VAR_H(tessedit_load_sublangs, "",
               "List of languages to load with this one");
  // Min acceptable orientation margin (difference in scores between top and 2nd
  // choice in OSResults::orientations) to believe the page orientation.
  double_VAR_H(min_orientation_margin, 7.0,
               "Min acceptable orientation margin");
  BOOL_VAR_H(textord_tabfind_show_vlines, false, "Debug line finding");
  BOOL_VAR_H(textord_use_cjk_fp_model, FALSE, "Use CJK fixed pitch model");
  BOOL_VAR_H(tessedit_init_config_only, false,
             "Only initialize with the config file. Useful if the instance is "
             "not going to be used for OCR but say only for layout analysis.");
  BOOL_VAR_H(textord_equation_detect, false, "Turn on equation detector");
```

Comment: This is useful!... but you might want to check how you implemented the other code snippet though. It does work in iOS. (Note: I put the code in a mixed mode wrapper.)

Answer (score 3):

There are approximately 660 variables. You can obtain the complete list by executing the PrintVariablesToFile API function.

```
textord_debug_tabfind   0
textord_debug_bugs  0
textord_testregion_left -1
textord_testregion_top  -1
textord_testregion_right    2147483647
textord_testregion_bottom   2147483647
textord_tabfind_show_partitions 0
....
```

Comment: I am not able to call that function. Do you know how to call that function in iOS environment?

Comment: Sorry, that method is part of the C API. The C++ API method is PrintVariables. Try to call that one instead. I don't know much about iOS to tell you more.