# how to change tesseract config to recognize § and apply with pdftools::pdf_ocr_text in R?

Tags: r, ocr, tesseract, pdftools

I am using `pdftools` in R to extract text from both scanned and text based PDF files. One problem is with the `§` character. This is not recognized by tesseract.

I looked at the following links:
[CRAN tesseract package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tesseract/vignettes/intro.html#read_from_pdf_files)

[SO link of a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007245/how-to-find-parameters-supported-in-tesseract-ocr-config-file)

[and this github page](https://shiring.github.io/text_analysis/2017/07/17/ocr_tesseract)

And I tried the following:

1. I found the configuration files using `tesseract_info()` and edited the `digits` file under `configs`.
   The `digits` file content was like this:

   `tessedit_char_whitelist 0123456789.`

After editing it looks like this:

```
tessedit_char_whitelist 0123456789-$§.
```

This did not change anything at all, I am still not able to extract `§`. They still appear as `8`.

2. After the 1st step failed, I tried the following:

   ```
   filepng <- pdftools::pdf_convert(filePathPDF, dpi = 600)

   specs <- tesseract("deu", options = list(tessedit_char_whitelist = "1234567890-.,;:qwertzuiopüasdfghjklöäyxcvbnmQWERTZUIOPÜASDFGHJKLÖÄYXCVBNM@ß€!$%&§/()=?+"))

   text <- tesseract::ocr(filepng, engine = specs)
   ```

This one failed too. I am by no means an expert on OCR and tesseract has room for improvements when it comes to documentation.

How can I add `§` to the list of characters to be recognized in the right way, so that it applies?

**Update**

The following works to recognize `§`, when I remove `language` from the argument list:

```
charlist <- tesseract(options = list(tessedit_char_whitelist = " 1234567890-.,;:qwertzuiopüasdfghjklöäyxcvbnmQWERTZUIOPÜASDFGHJKLÖÄYXCVBNM@ß€!$%&§/()=?+"))

text <- tesseract::ocr(filepng, engine = charlist)
```

But this time, I am losing German umlauts. I cannot find out how I can specify the language and the char_whitelist at the same time. According to the documentation, `tesseract()` accepts language argument and options argument. But this does not seem to work. Any ideas?

**Update:**
I tried using tesseract in command line (MacOS Catalina 10.15.7).

I converted a scanned PDF file first to an image then used this:

```
tesseract fileConverted.tiff fileToText
```

It creates `fileToText.txt`. It does recognize `§`. All of them are correctly recognized. But German umlauts are not recognized correctly, since I did not specify language at all. When I use the same command with the `language` argument

```
tesseract fileConverted.tiff fileToText -l deu
```

German umlauts are recognized properly but `§` is not.

The `digits` config file I changed is here:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.1.1/share/tessdata/configs
```

My understanding is: it is not a problem specific to R, but it occurs with tesseract itself. Setting `tessedit_char_whitelist` and the language at the same time does not seem to be possible or I am missing something horribly.

Comment: It seems that tesseract 4 [does not support setting a whitelist](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/751). Maybe it helps to downgrade to tesseract 3? Or maybe something else changed in the meantime, as the issue is already quite old?

Comment: I had a similar problem that it did not recognize the £ symbol. I retrained a models starting from an existing model and some gold data with image lines https://github.com/ropensci/tesseract/issues/50

Comment: `eng.trainnedata` seems to have the character § but `deu.trainneddata` does not. Can you try with both languages? `-l eng+deu` or `-l deu+eng`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said above, tesseract 4 does not support setting a whitelist. To go around that problem, you could use the command-line switch. You need to set OCR Engine mode to the "Original Tesseract only" with `--oem 0` then use `-c tessedit_char_whitelist=abc...` to pass your whitelist directly via the command-line.

Overall, it should look something like this :
`tesseract fileConverted.tiff fileToText --oem 0 -l deu -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789-$§`